# MYSQL Create or pick a Date into group, but unable to display correct amount

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I having a bit blocking issue on code, I am able to get total amount but unable to get amount in the order, which i am stuck on it and need your advice.

Here is a Screenshot a table of SQL data.

[image]

Here is a code that I  wrote

```
SELECT 
    settlement_start_date,
    settlement_end_date,
    SUM(total_amount) AS total_Amount,
    SUM(IF(transaction_type = 'order',
        amount,
        0)) AS 'Order'
FROM
    settlements
WHERE
    (settlement_end_date BETWEEN '2017-08-30' AND '2017-09-10')
```

the problem is 0000-00-00 date keep blocking me if I  type date on 29/08/2017 to 10/09/2017.

They will show an only Total amount on the first line but won't pick up their rest of amount, they are showing only 0.00. I have tried Settlement_id as a group but fail. is there another way to allow group as Settlement ID together as a total with a date?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those dates don't match your `WHERE` condition. You need to use `OR` to test for either condition.

```
SELECT 
    settlement_start_date,
    settlement_end_date,
    SUM(total_amount) AS total_Amount,
    SUM(IF(transaction_type = 'order',
        amount,
        0)) AS 'Order'
FROM
    settlements
WHERE
    (settlement_end_date BETWEEN '2017-08-30' AND '2017-09-10')
    OR settlement_end_date = '0000-00-00'
```